# Eclipse - Is it possible to commit linked files?

Tags: svn, eclipse-pdt

Is it possible to commit outside files that have been linked to a project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not typically, as far as I know.

Eclipse's integration with source control systems generally follows the idea that only project files are committed into the corresponding repository, and the file system boundaries are observed. Thus, stuff not under your project directory (and marked as external) will not be committed, especially if marked explicitly as external.

Your alternatives include creating soft links to the external files (I would avoid that),
or creating a separate eclipse project (With its own repository location) for the external files, and then adding project dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Uri. I'm using Eclipse for PHP coding and would like to keep some files in a WAMP installation. What do you think of the idea of opening a workspace on the main drive so a project can be created from the WAMP directory?

Comment: James, I haven't worked with PHP so I know a little about that, but it is fairly straightforward to create a language-independent project in Eclipse. You go to new -> project -> general, and then instead of default location put a path to a disk location. You will then have a second project in your current workspace, which you can then sync to a repository location (I usually use a separate SVN for these third-party items).